# sqlplus: password contains slash "/" is not accepted

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Maybe this is trivial for DB people but unfortunately not for me.

I spent hours with this but the solutions that I have found did not help. My DB password contains a `/` character and I think this confuses `sqlplus` and that is the reason why I am not able to log in. Let's say my password is `pass/word`.

**This is what I have tried so far:**

```
$ sqlplus MYUSER/pass/word@ABCDEF

$ sqlplus MYUSER/pass\/word@ABCDEF

$ sqlplus MYUSER/'pass/word'@ABCDEF

$ sqlplus MYUSER/'pass\/word'@ABCDEF

$ sqlplus MYUSER/"pass/word"@ABCDEF

$ sqlplus MYUSER/"pass\/word"@ABCDEF

$ sqlplus MYUSER/\""pass/word\""@ABCDEF
```

None of them above worked.

**Then I tried this way:**

```
$ sqlplus MYUSER@ABCDEF

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Fri Nov 19 15:10:13 2021
Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:
SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM|SYSBACKUP|SYSDG|SYSKM|SYSRAC}] [edition=value]]
where <logon> ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
      <proxy> ::= <proxyuser>[<username>][/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
Enter user-name: ^C
```

**And this way:**

```
$sqlplus /nolog
connect MYUSER@ABCDEF

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Fri Nov 19 15:10:13 2021
Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:
SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM|SYSBACKUP|SYSDG|SYSKM|SYSRAC}] [edition=value]]
where <logon> ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
      <proxy> ::= <proxyuser>[<username>][/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
Enter user-name: ^C
```

No result.

Google did not help.

What is the trick here that I need to use?

Comment: When you let `sqlplus` prompt you for the password, enter `"pass/word"` instead of `pass/word`.

Comment: `sqlplus myuser/\"pass/word\"` should also work so long as you set `TWO_TASK=ABCDEF`.

Comment: `sqlplus myuser/\"pass/word\"@ABCDEF` should also work.

Comment: Thx, they work like a charm. Maybe you can post them as a solution.

Comment: For future reference, many operating systems and/or applications take issue with different special characters in passwords - especially when logging in from a command line. In my experience, the only special character that is universally accepted from a command line without having to resort to escape gymnastics like this is the underscore: "_".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big idea is that the first and last character of what you type needs to be `"`. Then the interpreters (whether it's sqlplus or the RDBMS itself) will strip them and whatever remains is taken verbatim.

Your first four attempts aren't close but the final three are.

> $ sqlplus MYUSER/"pass/word"@ABCDEF

This one is nearly perfect except that the shell<sup>1</sup> gobbles up the `"` characters and so the forward slash is *not* taken verbatim.

> $ sqlplus MYUSER/"pass\/word"@ABCDEF

This one is also close but the backslash doesn't help and the quotes are still gobbled up.

> $ sqlplus MYUSER/\""pass/word\""@ABCDEF

Actually, this one will work but I suspect this is not precisely what you tried (i.e., it's a typo because SO handles backslashes in an unexpected way when you're quoting). In this example, the properly matched quote characters are "received" by the `sqlplus` `main` entry point.

All of the following should work for you.

1. Let `sqlplus` prompt you for the password and enter `"pass/word"` instead of `pass/word`.
2. `sqlplus myuser/\"pass/word\"` so long as you set `TWO_TASK=ABCDEF`.
3. `sqlplus myuser/\"pass/word\"@ABCDEF` # simplest imo
4. `sqlplus myuser/\""pass/word\""@ABCDEF`
5. `sqlplus myuser/\""pass/word"\"@ABCDEF`

**footnotes:**

1: If you're using a real operating system and not a Microsoft one.